# ADB Connection Error (CMD Fix not working)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried killing adb and starting it from CMD but still getting the error.
[image]

My Emulator(Geny and android emulator) doesn't recognized by android studio.

Comment: have you tried `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`?

Comment: Yes, I just have said that in my post.

Comment: Seems like port `5037` is bering used by another process.